# Convert String to Date in MS Access Data Macro

Tags: ms-access, vba, type-conversion, sharepoint-2013

I'm struggling to convert a string to a date in an MS Access 2010 Data Macro on a table that linked to a SharePoint 2013 List.

These work fine:

- > FormatDateTime(Now())
- > FormatDateTime(Date())
- > FormatDateTime([SharePointModifiedDate]) (where 'SharePointModifiedDate' is the field that contains the date that the record was last modified)

These don't work:

- > FormatDateTime('07/07/2017')
- > FormatDateTime("07/07/2017")
- > FormatDateTime("07/07/2017",2)
- > FormatDateTime("07/07/2017 00:00:00")

System is based on UK date/time.

Any help you could give would be most appreciated.

Comment: It asks for a date field not a string - wrap it in pound sign or hash symbol "#" instead of quotes - `#07/07/2017#`

Comment: This [link](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html) has a VBA function called `SQLDate` which I pass all my (UK) dates through and haven't had a problem since.  `SQLDate(Now())` returned `#07/24/2018 17:30:53#` and `SQLDate(Date)` returned `#07/24/2018#`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a DateTime value in a number of ways:

1. As a literal Date by surrounding the date with hash/pound symbols:

   ```
   FormatDateTime(#07/07/2017#)
   ```

   Note that this will interpret the date as `mm/dd/yyyy` unless the first number is greater than 12, forcing it to be interpreted as `dd/mm/yyyy`.

   To avoid possible confusion with the interpretation, you can specify the date in ISO 8601 format, i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd` to ensure there is no ambiguity:

   ```
   FormatDateTime(#2017-07-07#)
   ```
2. Using the `DateValue` function to convert from a string to date:

   ```
   FormatDateTime(DateValue('07/07/2017'))
   ```

   Again, this will by default interpret the string value in `mm/dd/yyyy` format unless of course the first value is greater than 12.
3. Using the `DateSerial` function:

   ```
   FormatDateTime(DateSerial(2017, 7, 7))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

All your attempts are for converting a date to a string.

However, the title asks for converting a string to a date, and this is what *DateValue* is for. Thus:

```
Dim TrueDate As Date

TextDate = "25-07-2018"
TrueDate = DateValue(TextDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question that works for me so I thought that I should post it here for others to benefit:

[image]

My problem was that I believed FormatDateTime() to be a conversion function; but it isn't.

Instead I used this:

> DateSerial(CDbl(Mid([strDate],2,4)),CDbl(Mid([strDate],7,2)),CDbl(Mid([strDate],10,2)))

(with strDate being " 2016-09-12T10:21:10  Status Updated to PO4.3").

This worked perfectly for me.